# Joining 3 Tables via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join 3 tables to access data from each table.   The main table in this case is going to be the Stats table.  So I need to access the Players table to get their NextOpponent and then I need access to the Defense table to run calculations on the NextOpponent.  Any ideas have to achieve all 3 of these.

Current SQL Statement: (Currently in an never ending loop of printing out duplicates)

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Stats
    INNER JOIN Defense ON Stats.Team =  Defense.Team
    INNER JOIN Players ON Defense.Team = Players.team";
```

Here is my database structure.

```
Players
-PID (Primary)
-Name
-NextOpponent

Stats
-PID (Primary)
-Name
-Touchdowns
-Receptions
-etc....

Defense
-Team (Unique)
-Points
```

So my intended output would be:

```
Chris Johnson
Next Opponent: IND
Defense Points: 100
```

UPDATE: I can now access the fields, however when I echo the defense points it actually returns the points of the teams defense the player is on not their next opponents defensive points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `GROUP BY p.id` ?

**UPDATE**

This was the final query:

`SELECT * FROM Stats s JOIN Players p ON p.PID = s.PID JOIN Defense d ON d.Team = p.upcoming GROUP BY p.PID`

Comment: This help fixed the looping issue. However it is not the complete answer.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM Stats s JOIN Players p ON p.id = s.id JOIN Defense d ON d.team = p.NextOpponent GROUP BY p.id;`

Comment: This was the final query thanks to your help.  `SELECT * FROM Stats s JOIN Players p ON p.PID = s.PID JOIN Defense d ON d.Team = p.upcoming GROUP BY p.PID`  Can you add it as your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Stats s, Defense d, Players p 
WHERE s.Team = d.Team AND d.Team = p.team;
```

Comment: I'm still having the looping issue, however it does look like this gives me access to all the fields I need.

Comment: If you keep getting the same you can also use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also, using this and trying to access the defense points it actually returns the points of the teams defense the player is on not their next opponent defense points.

Comment: Try flipping this `s.Team = d.Team` to this `d.Team = s.Team` ? You just need top play with the WHERE conditions a littlebit.

Comment: I flipped and it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't return endless data sets.  I'd suggest looking at your code to ensure you read the next record inside your loop.